# foreach with range does not work

Tags: php, foreach, range

here is my code:

```
   function my_function()
{
$states = array('schwarz', 'rot', 'blau');
foreach(range(0, 5) as $number) {
  foreach ($states as $state) {
    $result = "<img src=\"inventory_images/8.jpg\" onclick=\"changecolor(this)\" name=\"nummer.$number\" />";
    $testPath = "transactions/Ordner$number/$state.png";
    if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $result = $testPath;
    }
  }
  break;
}
return $result;
}
$imagesPerLine = array(1=>1, 2=>2); $default = 3;
$lines = array(1, 2, 3);
$html="";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
if (!isset($imagesPerLine[$line])) {
  $imagesPerLine[$line] = $default;
}
$html.= "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
  $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n", my_function());
}
$html.="</tr>\n";

}
echo $html;
```

and this is the output:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
</tr>
```

now i dont know how to configure my foreach part to get the name-value = n+1.the output should be:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.3" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.4" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="nummer.5" /></td>
</tr>
```

firstly i thought, "break;" or "return $result;" is placed wrong, but i dont think so now.
could anybody help me to change my script maybe??
thanks and greetings!!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but the range loop only ever runs with $number = 0 because you are breaking out of the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: `range()` works as expected: http://codepad.org/XDA8BBON. The problem is clearly somewhere else. But the `break` condition stops the loop after the first iteration. That seems illogical.

Comment: so where should i place break; when not after the first iteration?, i just want to to get second output, i posted..but i always get (name="nummer.0") and not (name="nummer.n+1") like i wanted. you know? greetings!

Comment: Did you solved the issue or still struggling with it?

Comment: still struggling with it Khawer Zeshan... :/ i deleted break; because i think there is no need, but i still get the first output..anybody could help me? greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed.  Because you return the string from your function, and print it outside, you need to change how you are doing it.  Currently, you're doing this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
  $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n", my_function());
}
```

Sounds to me like you need to make your function wrap its content with `<td>...</td>`, and also concatenate.  So inside your function you should do:

```
$result .= "<td>etc etc $number etc etc</td>\n";
```

It would also be good practice to put `$result = "";` at the top of that function.

Now, when you return `$result`, you should get all the stuff you put together inside those loops, and you add that to `$html` by changing your calling loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
  $html .= my_function();
}
```