# range() does not work with loop

Tags: php, loops, range

my main problem is that it seems like range() is not working fine in my double-loop...
here is my code i deal with:

```
   function my_function()
{
$states = array('schwarz', 'rot', 'blau');
$transactionIDs = range(1,10);
foreach($transactionIDs as $transactionID) {
  foreach ($states as $state) {
    $result = "<img src=\"inventory_images/8.jpg\" onclick=\"changecolor(this)\" name=\"number.".$transactionID."\" />";
    $testPath = "transactions/Ordner".$transactionID."/".$state.".png";
    if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $result = $testPath;
    }
    return $result;
    break;
  }
}
}
$bilderProZeile = array(1=>4,
                      2=>6);
$angabe = 3;
$eingesetzteBilder = array();
$zeilen = array(1, 2, 3);
$html="";
foreach ($zeilen as $zeile) {
if (!isset($bilderProZeile[$zeile])) {
  $bilderProZeile[$zeile] = $angabe;
}
$html.= "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $bilderProZeile[$zeile]; $i++) {
  $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n", my_function());
}
$html.="</tr>\n";
}
echo $html;
```

the output i get:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
<td><img src="inventory_images/8.jpg" onclick="changecolor(this)" name="number.1" /></td>
</tr>
```

everything is great, but it seems like range() does not work.
I defined the range 1-10 but i always get 1 (name="number.1") , why?
greetings and thanks!

Comment: You already have posted the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136542/foreach-with-range-does-not-work)

Comment: Hmm, but the code is different...  I wonder which version is being used.

Comment: "range() does not work with loop" - nonsense. you'll waste a lot of time if you don't trust the language. the problem is always in your code...

Answer (score 1):

You always return from your function inside  the inner loop after outputting the first line:

```
return $result;
break;
```

You would need to remove both the lines above.

Comment: ehm ok but how do i get any output when i remove "return $result"; ?

Comment: You put it at the end of the function!  The problem with having it inside the loop is that the loop doesn't loop - it just returns.  I answered your other question too, with more detail about what you should probably be doing.